# Make nav-menus.php available for editor

Tags: menus, user-roles, editor, capabilities

I've removed the 'Appearance' menu from the admin sidebar :

```
function clean_menu() {
       remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' ); 
}
add_action('admin_menu','clean_menu');
```

Then, I added the `nav-menu.php` manually as a parent in the sidebar :

```
function menu_reorder($menu_ord) {
    if (!$menu_ord) return true;

    return array(
        ...,
        'nav-menus.php',
        ...
    );
}
add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'menu_reorder'); 
add_filter('menu_order', 'menu_reorder');
```

It is working great as admin, but when I login as an editor, I am **not authorized** to go to `nav-menu.php`, although I have enabled required capabilities:

```
function manage_users() {
    if ( get_option( 'add_cap_editor_once' ) != 'done' ) {

        $edit_editor = get_role('editor');

        $edit_editor->add_cap('edit_themes');
        $edit_editor->add_cap('edit_theme_options');

        update_option( 'add_cap_editor_once', 'done' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'manage_users' );
```

Any ideas why this is not working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now i understand :

There was something wrong due to previous manipulations.

**`add_cap`** is **modifying the database**, so somehow i had written over other capabilities and it broke the wanted result.

So i cleaned the role with the use of a few **`remove_cap`**, put my functions back and voilà !